# K-theory functoriality understanding

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, functors, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Reading some K-theory I understand the construction of the abelian group $K(X)$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. However, I read in most of the references that $K$ is also a functor. Why? Which are the categories that are being connected by $K$? What are their respective morphisms? This is confusing for me.

**My thoughts**: 
Since 
$$K:\mathrm{Vect}(X) \to \mathrm{Vect}(X) \times\mathrm{Vect}(X)\Big/\sim \;$$ is a mapping from an abelian monoid to an abelian group, $K$ would be a functor from the category of abelian monoids to the category of abelian groups. But an abelian group is also an abelian monoid. Does not this imply that $K$ is just a morphism? Then, which categories does the function $K$ join?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The categories are compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous maps, and Abelian groups with group homomorphisms. The functor is contravariant, and is induced
via pullback of vector bundles.

Comment: so you mean, a map $f:X \to Y$ (in the category of comp. haus. spaces) induces a mapping $f^*:K(Y) \to K(X)$? So... Since any bundle $[E_1 - E_2] \in K(Y)$ is being mapped to the pullback bundle $[f^*(E_1) - f^*(E_2)] \in K(X)$?

Comment: Yes${{{}}}{}{}$.